# OutOfMemory Error need solution

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I know it's a common problem for working with bitmaps but I don't know how to go on this with example. Especially because the size of the image view is not big that you would say it should cause a memory error. I think it's because I create the bitmaps to often instead of creating it once ant display it every five seconds but don't know how to do it. First of all the code for creating the bitmaps.

java class `trapViews`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int x = 20;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(900 - 200) + 200;
    rnd = new Random();
    //Linke Seite

    System.gc();

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stachelnstart);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, i1, 300, true);
        float left = (float) 0;
        float top = (float) (getHeight() - resizedBitmap.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, left, top, paint);

        //rechte Seite
        Bitmap images = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stachelnstart1);
        Bitmap resizedBitmaps = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(images, getWidth()-resizedBitmap.getWidth()-OwlHole, 300, true);
        float left1 = (float) (getWidth() - resizedBitmaps.getWidth());
        float top1 = (float) (getHeight() - resizedBitmaps.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmaps, left1, top1, paint);
    }
}
```

Creates a drawable on the right and left side of the screen with an random length.

Now I call this every 5 sec in the `MainActivity` with a `Handler`:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.gc();
        traps();
        h.postDelayed(this,5000); // Handler neustarten
    }
}

private void traps() {
    container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    trapViews tv = new trapViews(this);
    container.addView(tv,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    //tV.setImageCount(8);
    h.postDelayed(r, 5000);
}
```

first of all, it's working like I want it to work. But every time a new drawable appears my game is lagging and after 5-6 times creating one its crashing down

The `System.gc()` and `bitmap.recycle` functions aren't working really well. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Why read and decode again and again in method scope?  Do it once when you construct the object and reuse it.

Comment: yea thats what i want to do. But i dont get how. Do you have any example?

Comment: Do it in the Runnable/Callable class constructor OR in the class that owns onDraw.  I'd prefer the second one.

Comment: You can try using java-profiler on your project. This link can help u get better understanding of memory leaks https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java

Comment: would i be to much work for u if u show it to me on my code? i am too much amateur to know what i have to change now ^^ honestly i´m really happy to get this far ..

Comment: Also gc is not affecting all memory used by non recycled Bitmaps

Comment: You have so many mistakes in your code. Most common is that `onDraw` is a frequent repeatable method. Any object creation operation is time-consuming, so you definitely shouldn't create objects in onDraw. Use pre-layout and other 
interceptors for that.

Comment: oh something i really like to hear but thanks. okay i didnt hear about these two possibilities before but i will try to get into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the bitmaps every 5 seconds which is not a good idea as they are always the same. You should create them once instead

```
 trapViews extends View{
    Bitmap image;
        Bitmap resizedBitmap;


        //rechte Seite
       Bitmap images ;
        Bitmap resizedBitmaps;

trapViews(Context c){
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stachelnstart);
images = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stachelnstart1);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int x = 20;
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(900 - 200) + 200;
        rnd = new Random();
        //Linke Seite
          //I have left this bitmap in the here as it is affected by the random int
         resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, i1, 300, true);
            float left = (float) 0;
            float top = (float) (getHeight() - resizedBitmap.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, left, top, paint);

          //create this bitmap here as getWidth() will return 0 if created in the view's constructor
        if(resizedBitmaps == null)
         resizedBitmaps = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(images, getWidth()-resizedBitmap.getWidth()-OwlHole, 300, true);
            float left1 = (float) (getWidth() - resizedBitmaps.getWidth());
            float top1 = (float) (getHeight() - resizedBitmaps.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmaps, left1, top1, paint);

}


}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer if this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Remember to call Bitmap.recycle() after you replace a bitmap or when it's not visible anymore.
Creating mutiple bitmaps is not the problem but left unused objects without making use of recycle to free up memory.

Comment: yes i know but i think it should be okay to display 10 bitmaps at the same time before i recycle them. and its starting to lag at the very first one bitmap i display so i dont think my problem have sth to do with the recycle function

Comment: Whats the size of the bitmap in its initial state?